# Use same ui-view template for multiple states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, angular-ui-router

I am using angularjs ui-router for a cordova app. I am trying to reuse a ui-view template (left-panel) for multiple states. This ui-view is for almost all the states except one state. I tried to refer many tutorials but still not able to implement what I want. Here is my code in **app.js**:

```
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', [
  'ui.router',
]);

angularApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
  $stateProvider
    .state('root', {
      abstract: true,
      views: {
        'left-panel': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/common-left-panel.html',
        },
      }
    })
    .state('root.home', {
      url: '/',
      views: {
        'container@': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
        }
      }
    })
    .state('root.settings', {
      url: 'settings',
      views: {
        'container@': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/settings.html',
        }
      }
    })
    .state('root.category', {
      url: 'category/:catId',
      views: {
        'container@': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/category-nodes.html',
          controller: 'ListCatNodesCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
});
```

This is in **index.html**

```
<div ui-view="left-panel"></div>
<a ui-sref="root.settings">Settings</a>
<div ui-view="container"></div>
```

With this code, the home page is rendered properly. But when I click on the settings link, there isn't any change in screen or url. In rendered DOM, I get `<a ui-sref="root.settings" href="#settings">Settings</a>`. The same holds for category page as well. Basically I am developing an android app using cordova and angularjs. Loads of thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using anchor tag for settings? Can you explain first line of your question again?

Comment: I want to  use the left panel view for all states except one state. Thats y I made it as abstract. i need to link to settings page using a button. ui sref doesn't seem to work at all

Comment: Try this `<a ui-sref=".settings">settings</a>` or this `<a ui-sref="settings">settings</a>`

Comment: Actually i tried them as well but same result.i think I am doing it wrong in defining the ui view

Comment: Mention url as `url: '.settings',` put a dot then try as my above comment.